# Restricting user from multiple loggins

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, openjpa

I have come across a requirement where have to restrict a user from multiple logins. If user logged in from Firefox and trying to login through IE should restrict saying you are already logged in through different browser or system. I am using CAS sso and spring security in my web application. Suppose possible, where it would be good to handle? CAS or web applicatoion?

Comment: As per my knowledge, this is my first question on stack overflow(Don't remember if I asked any before). I am not aware of the rules to post a question. I am still seeing its showing [on hold]. Admins/Moderators, please do the needful.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security has a special feature for you case called [Concurrent Session Control](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-sessions). You can prevent a user from logged in multiple times by adding following tags into your http config :

```
  <http>
    ...
    <!-- Preventing simultaneous logins -->
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
    ...
  </http>
```

Example taken directly from the official documentation. It will work for your IE / FF case.

Comment: @MaksymDemikdas: Thanks a lot for your answer. It saved me from banging my head digging in depth. Let me give a try. And just need your advice too. I am using CAS and web application with spring security. Where would I be doing this? Its good to do at CAS or in the web application?

Comment: You are welcome! Could you show your security xml file? Normally even in the case of case you must have `http` tag somewhere in your conf.

Comment: <sec:http entry-point-ref="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint" auto-config="true">
    <sec:logout logout-url="/services/logout.html" logout-success-url="/services/loggedOut.html"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="casProcessingFilter" after="CAS_FILTER"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="${cas.securityContext.serviceProperties.adminRoles}"/>
    <security:session-management>
     <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
 </security:session-management>
  </sec:http>

Comment: You have everything in place. Is it working?

Comment: Nope. It's not working. If I am trying to login from different broswers, from both the browsers its allowing to login. I should be doing this at CAS side or web application? Because CAS is the one who authenticates the user.

Comment: Normally it works fine (without CAS). I think CAS filter changes something. Maybe it reuses existed server side session for second login attempt?

Comment: Concurrency-Control should be done at CAS or web application which is integrated with Sprin-Security?

Comment: At web application (normally). I don't know how you can do it at CAS level.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But web application is not the one which authenticates user after login. CAS is also a web application with Spring and Spring security.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a user's login status, you need to store a session ID in cookie. Cookie can not be shared between different browsers. So you can distinguish different sessions by different session IDs stored in corresponding browsers. Then you can find out whether a user has already logged in from another browser.

Comment: Thanks Weibo for your valuable comment. I am not clear. Could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: @JackSparrow: What kind of web server and web framework do you use?

Comment: Apache tomcat and Spring MVC integrated with Spring Security and CAS for SSO.

Comment: @JackSparrow: Then how do you check whether a user has logged in or not? Please show a small piece of code.

Comment: Once user authenticated through CAS, redirect to application home page. Its a big piece of code. Sorry for that.

Comment: @JackSparrow: Seems that so many things are done by framework and not under your control. What about generating a token(UUID e.g.) every time when a user is trying to login, and then store the token in both cookie and user session. Next time, when the logged in user is trying to re-login from another browser, you could found the token in session, but from the browser cookie. Then you can discover it is a login request from a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Let me give a try. In mean time I was thinking of storing user session in DB. Don't know this is the recommended one or not.

Comment: @JackSparrow: That depends. If you want the session to be persistence, then store in DB is OK, unless you need very high performance. Or use memcached or redis to temporally store the session in memory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. I think got a green light to go ahead. Appreciate.